# Jackson partial working, cannot return List<Object> or Collection<Object>

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using spring MVC & hibernate for my webapp.
Problem is now I can generate json if return an object, but not List.
Anything I miss out?

(1) If I access this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/mobile/userDetail")
public UserDetail generateUserDetailJson(){
    return userDetailService.getUserDetail(1);
}
```

result okay, I will get this json return:

```
{"udId":1,"udTitle":"Mr","udUsername":"username","udFirstname":"firstname","udLastname":"lastname","udGender":"male","udPhoto":"c:/folder/gg.jpg","udPassword":"password","udEmail":"email@email.com","udPhoneHome":"01234567890","udPhoneMobile":"","udType":"customer","udLanguage":"ms","udLoginLast":1466875438000,"udLoginCount":0,"udCreateDatetime":1466875438000,"udStatus":2,"bodyMeasures":[{"bmId":1,"bmHeight":171,"bmNeck":null,"bmShoulder":null,"bmArm":null,"bmChest":null,"bmWaist":null,"bmHip":null,"bmInseam":null,"bmThigh":null,"bmCalf":null,"bmFoot":null,"bmHead":null,"bmCreateDatetime":1466875438000,"bodyMeasureHistories":[]}],"addresses":[],"userDetailHistories":[]}
```

(2)But if I access this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/mobile/userDetails")
public Collection<UserDetail> generateUserDetailsJson(){
    Collection<UserDetail> collection = userDetailService.listUserDetails(); 
    return collection;
}
```

I will get this exception.

> Info:   Hibernate: 
>       select
>           this_.ud_id as ud_id1_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_title as ud_title2_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_username as ud_usern3_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_firstname as ud_first4_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_lastname as ud_lastn5_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_gender as ud_gende6_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_photo as ud_photo7_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_password as ud_passw8_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_email as ud_email9_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_phoneHome as ud_phon10_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_phoneMobile as ud_phon11_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_type as ud_type12_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_language as ud_lang13_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_loginLast as ud_logi14_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_loginCount as ud_logi15_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_createDatetime as ud_crea16_6_0_,
>           this_.ud_status as ud_stat17_6_0_ 
>       from
>           faddistwardrobedb.user_detail this_
>   Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:264)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:225)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:173)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:130)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Severe:   PWC6117: File "null" not found

My spring configuration file already setup:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

And I'm using spring 4.3.0 & hibernate 4.3.11

```
jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar

jackson-core-2.7.0.jar

jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar

javax.el-2.2.4.jar

javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
```

Entity table already configure jackson:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "body_measure", catalog = "faddistwardrobedb")
public class BodyMeasure implements java.io.Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "ud_id")
    private UserDetail userDetail;
    //etc....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_detail", catalog = "faddistwardrobedb")
public class UserDetail implements java.io.Serializable {

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userDetail")
    //etc.....
}
```

Anything I'm miss out? Or the library got conflict with each other? 
Thanks.

Comment: This part of the stacktrace:  Warning: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;) leads me to believe that another version of jackson-databind is being pulled in, as this method didn't exist prior to v2.5.  You say you're using v2.7, which should have this method.  What's likely happening is that spring or hibernate has a dependency on jackson-databind < v2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, but don't know details what go wrong.
My solution:
Glassfish 4.1 -> glassfish 4.1.1
recompile and run, problem solved.
Hope able help someone facing same error.