# Jackson issue in Spring.MVC on WildFly server

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, wildfly

I found the question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129930/jackson-partial-working-cannot-return-listobject-or-collectionobject](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/) for which I was interested in finding out the answer for solving:

> 11:28:26,333 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-11) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]>
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
>   ...

In my case it occurs with the Spring REST API when I use the WAR on a WildFly (8.x) server, but the same WAR on a Tomcat (8.5) server works fine.
I am still trying to find a solution in order to have it also working on a WildFly server.

Note that I was following the tutorial [spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/) but installed initially the WildFly (8.x) server via Eclipse.

I have also modified the ***POM.xml*** dependencies as follow hoping to solve the Jackson dependency issue:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <jackson.version>2.7.5</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

If anyone has an idea, I am all ears.

Comment: Having closer look at [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.1.RELEASE) I figured out there was a mismatch between _springframework.version_ and _jackson.version_. **Changing jackson.version to 2.8.1 in the _pom.xml_ solved the problem**

Comment: Actually, correcting the version did not solve the problem. While testing the assumed fix my Tomcat server was still on and the Angular service was pointing to the Tomcat port when the WAR got installed on WildFly. Meaning that the Front-end was on WildFly and calling the back-end on Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You should do one thing go inside the wildfly server

\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\fasterxml\jackson\core
then go inside  check your jar versions it should be 2.8 or above for all core libs.
jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
jackson-core-2.8.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar

And change for all jars versions mapping inside the  module.xml with latest version name like this