# Error with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType [Jasperreports] [Spring MVC]

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jackson, jasper-reports

I'm working with `Spring MVC 4.3.4` and `Jasperreports 6.3.1` in a RESTful web project (Maven project in Netbeans). When I get an arraylist of objects in the controller, this error appears:

```
Grave:   Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:265)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:232)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
... 43 more
```

I reviewed the dependencies of `JasperReports 6.3.1` and I saw that the used version of the Jackson library is `2.1.4` (a bit old), and even in version `6.4.0` they also use that version.

My question is How do I solve this problem? Because in my `pom.xml` I tested including the latest version of Jackson (`2.8.5`) and still it seems that the project will not take it.

My `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsondoc-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

A little example of a get resource in my controller with json-doc annotations:

```
//------------ LISTAR ----------------
@ApiMethod(
    path = "/answers",
    description = "Lista las respuestas registradas.",
    verb = ApiVerb.GET,
    produces =
    {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    },
    visibility = ApiVisibility.PUBLIC,
    stage = ApiStage.ALPHA
)
@ApiErrors(
    apierrors =
    {
        @ApiError(code = "500", description = "Error del servidor al procesar la solicitud."),
    }
)
@ApiResponseObject(clazz = Answer.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Answer>> list() throws Exception
{
    List<Answer> list = answerService.list();

    if (list.isEmpty())
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Any luck solving this @christian-mercado ??

Comment: @Hoof Nothing yet... :( What I did was downgrading Spring to 4.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: I had the same error.. this works for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098329/jackson-issue-in-spring-mvc-on-wildfly-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never is too late, but I had the same problem with `Spring MVC 4.3.5` on `Wildfly-8.2.1`. My solution are like [@Tiago Coelho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185598/error-with-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-objectwri#comment74566237_41185598) mentioned. Replace in `\WildFly-8.2.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\fasterxml\jackson\core`, inside the three subfolders jackson-annotations, jackson-core and jackson-databind, the jar file for the lastest from jackson-core in maven repository, and then modify the file call `module.xml` replacing the version of the old jar for the new one. This work for me, Cheers.